# GAE/J datastore : how to build an IN query with JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to query a collection of entities by its key in the Google App Engine datastore.  This is the query I am trying to execute with no success:

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Fix.class);
query.setFilter("__key__ IN param");
query.declareParameters("com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key param");
query.execute(list); // list is an array of keys
```

And the error I get is:

```
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Portion of expression could not be parsed: IN param
```

Is it possible to use build an IN query with JDO or the low level API that finds entities by key?

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be confusing the JDO and JPA syntax:  see examples on [this](http://gae-java-persistence.blogspot.com/2009/12/queries-with-and-in-filters.html) page

JPA:

```
select from Person where
    favoriteFood IN ('cheeseburger', 'pizza', 'fried chicken')
    order by favoriteFood, age
```

JDO:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(
    "select from Person where :p1.contains(favoriteFood) order by favoriteFood, age");
q.execute(Arrays.asList("cheeseburger", "pizza", "fried chicken"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried examples from [this page](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html)? Something like:

```
query.addFilter("__key__", Query.FilterOperator.IN, param);
```

Note that `param` should be a list.